# Trying to deploy Symfony on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - setfacl not working?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, deployment, access-control-list

**Disclaimer:** I already [asked this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920306/trying-to-deploy-symfony-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-setfacl-not-working) but it's kind of urgent and I'm getting no responses and I figure ServerFault might be the better place to post this anyways.  If I get an answer on here I'll delete the other one.

I'm following the guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-application-to-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) (admittedly it's a little dated) to deploy my first Symfony 4 project to production. It was going all good until I got to the file permissions.  I did the steps specifically in Step 4 of the link :

```
sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R 750 /var/www/html
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rX /var/www/html/project
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX /var/www/html/project/var/cache /var/www/html/project/var/log
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX /var/www/html/project/var/cache /var/www/html/project/var/log
```

That gives me

```
getfacl /var/www/html/project

# file: var/www/html/project/
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
```

and

```
getfacl /var/www/html/project/var/cache

# file: var/www/html/project/var/cache
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

However when I go to run the web app I get a blank page and the error log shows

> [crit] 3116#3116: *12 stat() "/var/www/html/project/public/"
>   failed (13: Permission denied)

So it seems the setfacl isn't working?  What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better guide for permissions?

**EDIT:** I just read [here](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=acl) that:

> To use ACL, it's necessary to use filesystems which can use ACL
>   function like ext2/ext3/ext4 or xfs and also necessary to enable ACL
>   option on those filesystems.

My drive is encrypted (done during installation). Could that be why this isn't working?  If this is the case, what alternatives would I have?

Comment: not sure why you did `myuser:myuser` on `/var/www/html`, however `chmod o+x /var/www/html` is required for the www-data user to traverse down it.

Comment: Actually, I had JUST figured this out like 10 minutes before your comment and applied it.  I tried the site again and got the same blank page so I thought it was the same issue, but now in the log I just saw it's getting a SSL protocol error instead - meaning it must be getting past the file permissions.  Guess this was it :)  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the `www-data` user isn't a member of the `myuser` group, it requires `+x` permissions to descend through the `/var/www/html` directory. The existing permissions in the question are '750'. To change this:

```
chmod o+x /var/www/html
```